# Counting number of downloads per file name -- somehow some users end up with way more than they downloaded

Tags: php

Below I have code that outputs a large file in chunks (to save memory) and each time a file is requested to be downloaded a counter is incremented. I have tested this in multiple browsers and it seems to work as expected. But I have one user who recorded 578 downloads of one file and another that reported over 9000 of a file that was downloaded. My bandwidth charges don't indicate this happened.

The only thing I can think of is if they use a download accelerator that makes multiple connections.

Can you see any other possibilities?

```
if (isset($_GET['gf']) && $eligible) 
{
    $_GET['file'] = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : FILE_SOURCE;
    if (is_valid_file($_GET['file'])) 
    {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($_GET['file']));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($_GET['file'])); 

        echo readfile_chunked($_GET['file'], true, $auth);
        exit;
    }
}
// credit: http://teddy.fr/blog/how-serve-big-files-through-php
define('CHUNK_SIZE', 1024*1024);

function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes = true, $auth = false) {
    $download_column = false;

    switch($filename)
    {
        case FILE_SOURCE:
            $download_column = 'manual_downloads';
            break;
        case FILE_WIN_INSTALLER:
            $download_column = 'win_downloads';
            break;
        case FILE_MAC_INSTALLER:
            $download_column = 'mac_downloads';
            break;
        case FILE_LINUX_32_INSTALLER:
            $download_column = 'linux_32_downloads';
            break;
        case FILE_LINUX_64_INSTALLER:
            $download_column = 'linux_64_downloads';
            break;
    }

    if ($download_column && $auth)
    {
        $auth = mysql_real_escape_string($auth);
        $query = "UPDATE payments SET $download_column = $download_column + 1 WHERE auth = '$auth'";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
    $buffer = '';
    $cnt =0;

    // $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($handle === false) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if ($retbytes) {
            $cnt += strlen($buffer);
        }
    }

    $status = fclose($handle);
    if ($retbytes && $status) {
        return $cnt;
    }

    return $status;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your code, but you have several ways to trace the issue.

First and simplest is to log your downloads each time this script is going to get called. This way you can see the information corresponding to the script's malfunctioning if it is by multiple connections of accelerators.

Second is to restrict your users to download. You can make a table and hold their IP addresses and downloads times in it and then give them the permission to download according to that table. This way even multiple connections won't get past when there is a restriction to download based on time.

Comment: Thanks, I checked apache logs and their was 900 requests in the past 2 days with a bunch of different IPS all from China. How does this happen?

Comment: @ChrisMuench This seems a lot like a breach. Maybe someone has ran a PERL script or something on your website to make it flooded with requests. I suggest that you make it strict to authenticated users.

Comment: I checked with my host, there wasn't a breech, but the URL for downloading was found it. I am guessing the customer who purchased the script got hacked or shared the link. I changed the authentication link and it hasn't happened. Every customer gets a unique download link which is a hash of their order number and the current date. I could add additional security for login, but that would make it tough for a user.